# Outlook email text formatting from Python application

Tags: python, outlook

I have a use-case where I ask users to provide some failure notes (via. application configuration) that my application can send to them via outlook email when application fails or crashes. They provide these notes as a plain text in application configuration file:

For example:

> failure_note: "Job $name failed with $exception, please do $steps to
>   get this fixed".

My application will attach some other common content to the mail, substitute $ variables with runtime values in failure_notes provided by user in the configuration file, attach failure note in the email content and send this email to user when failure happens.

Now my user wants to make the failure_notes bold and red, and they want a short and sweet syntax for doing so. How can this be done?

Note: Application is written in Python

Answer (score 2):

You can format emails as html. Format the failure_notes with inline css.

Take a look at the html example from these docs:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Thanks Austin. I am pretty sure users wont be comfortable writing CSS since they are not programmers but also from a general standpoint, such failure_note will look quite hard to parse from a human standpoint. I was hoping for something that can be done with something like 

failure_note bold red : NOTE_CONTENT

Comment: I guess I will have to build some machinery to understand such syntax and generate HTML internally.